# Android play and loop audio

Tags: android, audio

I'm trying to make a simple android app that plays and loops through one audio file (like white noise). I'm not sure how audio works with apps, download it to SD card? How do I do this? And how do I loop through it, until "stop" is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your audio files are static, ship them in your app`s res/raw directory. This is how you can play and loop them from there:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.yoursound);
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.start();
```

For stopping, just call

```
mp.stop();
```

Comment: thank you. how do i ship them to the app's res/raw directory?

Comment: Simply create a new directory under your project's res folder, call it raw, and paste your files there.